# OpenGL ES texture degrades in quality

Tags: ios, c, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to draw a Core Graphics image generated **(at screen resolution)** into OpenGL. However, the image is rendering more aliased than the CG output (antialiasing is disabled in CG). **The text is the texture** (the blue background is respectively drawn in Core Graphics for the first image and OpenGL for the second).

**CG Output:**
[image: mmm lovely and smooth]

**OpenGL Render (in simulator):**

[image: ewww]

**Framebuffer setup:**

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &onscrRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, onscrRenderBuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:self.layer];

glGenFramebuffers(1, &onscrFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, onscrFramebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, onscrRenderBuffer);
```

**Texture Loading Code:**

```
-(GLuint) loadTextureFromImage:(UIImage*)image {

    CGImageRef textureImage = image.CGImage;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

    GLubyte* spriteData = (GLubyte*) malloc(width*height*4);

    CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage);
    CGContextRef c = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4, cs, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(cs);

    CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, -CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(c).size.height);

    CGContextDrawImage(c, (CGRect){CGPointZero, {width, height}}, textureImage);
    CGContextRelease(c);

    GLuint glTex;
    glGenTextures(1, &glTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTex);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei)width, (GLsizei)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    free(spriteData);

    return glTex;
}
```

**Vertices:**

```
struct vertex {
    float position[3];
    float color[4];
    float texCoord[2];
};

typedef struct vertex vertex;

const vertex bgVertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {0, 167.0/255.0, 253.0/255.0, 1}, {1, 0}}, // BR (0)
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 222.0/255.0, 1.0, 1}, {1, 1}}, // TR (1)
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 222.0/255.0, 1.0, 1}, {0, 1}}, // TL (2)
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 167.0/255.0, 253.0/255.0, 1}, {0, 0}} // BL (3)
};

const vertex textureVertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0}}, // BR (0)
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1}}, // TR (1)
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1}}, // TL (2)
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}} // BL (3)
};

const GLubyte indicies[] = {
    3, 2, 0, 1
};
```

**Render Code:**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

GLsizei width, height;
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &width);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &height);

glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bgVertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*3));
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*7));

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indicies)/sizeof(indicies[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureVertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);

glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*3));
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*7));

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indicies)/sizeof(indicies[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I am using the blend function `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` in case that has anything to do with it.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: You say you're first drawing the text into a CGImage using CoreGraphics. What does the output from that look like, *before* you use it as a GL texture?

Comment: added the CG output the the OP

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't have an answer for what your problem *is*, but I can tell you what it *isn't*. Multisampling only affects rasterization of polygon edges, and you're looking at texture content. Probably this has something to do with your texture filtering modes and/or the size and scale factor of your viewport.

Comment: agreed... I have edited OP to focus question on texture importing & rendering

Comment: That you're setting the viewport based on `self.frame` is a warning sign. Where are you setting up your render buffers? Remember, view sizes are measured [in points](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15), and depending on the native scale factor of your screen, each point may have 2x or more as many pixels.

Comment: (On a related note, `GLKView` does all the scale factor and multisampling setup for you, as well as various other GL correctness and performance things that are easy to miss. If you don't have a specific reason to avoid it, it can be a big help.)

Comment: well, I would like my code to be as multi-platform as possible (CG stuff can be fairly easily exported as assets) and plus I'm partly doing this to learn about OpenGL. I have updated OP to include framebuffer init code and changed the viewport frame to use the renderbuffer size. The results are unchanged.

Comment: What's the `contentScaleFactor` of your view? Does it match the `nativeScaleFactor` of your device screen?

Comment: well... I didn't specify it... I assumed it would default to the screen scale... apparently it doesn't! That fixed the problem! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98848/discussion-between-rickster-and-originaluser2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GL-rendered output looks all pixelated because it has fewer pixels.  Per the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW11), the default scale factor for a `CAEAGLLayer` is 1.0, so when you set up your GL render buffers, you get one pixel in the buffer per point. (Remember, a point is a unit of UI layout, which on modern devices with Retina displays works out to several hardware pixels.) When you render that buffer full-screen, everything gets scaled up (by about [2.61x on an iPhone 6(s) Plus](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)).

To render at the native screen resolution, you need to increase the [`contentScaleFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentScaleFactor) of your view. (Preferably, you should do this early on, before, setting up renderbuffers, so that they get the new scale factor from the view's layer.)

Watch out, though: you want to use [the `UIScreen` property `nativeScale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/nativeScale), not `scale`. The `scale` property reflects UI rendering, where, on iPhone 6(s) Plus, everything gets done at 3x and then scaled down slightly to the native resolution of the display. The `nativeScale` property reflects the number of *actual device pixels* per point — if you're doing GPU rendering, you want to target that so you don't sap performance by drawing more pixels than you need to. (On current devices other than the "Plus" iPhones, `scale` and `nativeScale` are the same. But using the latter is probably a good insurance policy.)

You can avoid a lot of these kinds of issues (and others) by letting [`GLKView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKView_ClassReference/index.html) do renderbuffer setup for you. Even if you're writing cross-platform GL, that part of your code is going to have to be pretty platform- and device-specific anyway, so you might as well reduce the amount of it that you have to write and maintain.

<sup>(Addressing previous edits of the question, for posterity's sake: this has nothing to do with multisampling or the quality of the GL texture data. Multisampling has to do with rasterization of polygon edges — points in the interior of a polygon get one fragment per pixel, but points on the edges get multiple fragments whose colors are blended in the resolve stage. And if you bind the texture to an FBO and `glReadPixels` from it, you'll find the image is pretty much the same one you put in.)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much for your help, very informative.